# How can I make JSF2 i18n work for Hindi website?

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I am building a JSF2.x based website with i18n feature. The first non-english language I am using is Hindi. Even you I have got all the resource bundle intact and when the Form is displayed, all values are intact, as can be seen in the top part of the attached screenshot. How ever, when the user moves to next "input confirm" screen, there is no Hindi anymore, only gibberish.

If anyone has experience in building Java(EE) i18n websites, please advise.

Many Thanks
[image]

Comment: This cannot be pure jsf. JSF doecnot have a 'rich' texteditor

Comment: this is the [primfaces texteditor](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml). do you experience the same behaviour when you add english text. can you show the source code of these fields

Comment: Hello, Many Thanks for looking into this. I have removed the PF text-editor and just using h:inputTextarea . Unfortunately, the issue is still the same for the non-english characters (hindi), but english inputs are spot on.

Comment: Also, could I politely request the admin of this post that this issue is not a duplicate one and is very must a different one! Thanks.